# Scala NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, maven

I am new to Scala. I have this code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path, FileSystem}

/**
 * Created by serban on 19/01/16.
 */
object TestHadoop {
 def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {


   val namenodeEndpoint = "hdfs://123.45.123.45:8020"
   val conf = new Configuration
   conf.set("fs.defaultFS", namenodeEndpoint)

   val fs = FileSystem.newInstance(conf)

   val path = new Path("/user/ubuntu")

   val fileStatus = fs.listFiles(path,false)

   println("Hello world "+fileStatus.getClass)

   while(fileStatus.hasNext())
     {
       println("FS: "+fileStatus.next())
     }


 }
}
```

When I run it from Maven, it runs OK. But I moved the compiled class to another machine and ran it in the command line via `scala TestHadoop`. This is what I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at TestHadoop$.main(TestHadoop.scala:13)
    at TestHadoop.main(TestHadoop.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:56)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:44)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.findClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.scala$tools$nsc$util$ScalaClassLoader$$super$loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:50)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.loadClass(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

It has a problem with my first import. When I run it in Maven, Maven knows how to solve this dependency.

**Question**: What can I do to run this example on my machine from the command line?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Comment: which command you use to run it in the other machine?

Comment: do you package your sample into a jar file or just copy a single class to the other machine?

Comment: you need either to use the -cp option to run the required class or build a fat jar from Maven in order to have all in one runnable unit

Comment: is there anything missing in your classpath? compare both machine to know the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `NoClassDefFoundError` error because you are simply invoking your class without passing to Scala the required external libraries. Maven has already any defined dependencies as part of its classpath, hence external libraries are detected at runtime.

You need to use the `-cp` option of Scala and pass to it the required jar files (the external libraries), although this approach may be error prone and not maintainable for large set of dependencies.

Alternatively, you could add to your pom the following:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}-with-dependencies</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Note: if you already have plugins configured, just add the plugin element of the [Maven Shade Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

This configuration will create a far jar using your artifactId and version and adding as a suffix the `-with-dependencies` token. Just run:

```
mvn package
```

And you will find the new jar in the target folder.

You can then use this jar (and not just the compiled file) in another machine and run it as following:

```
scala -cp yourproject-yourversion-with-dependencies.jar TestHadoop
```